# GPU crashes when binding something not valid in directx 11

Tags: c++, c, gpu, directx, directx-11

I'm a beginner with **DirectX11** and i got a small GPU error,it is when i try to bind **VertexShader** or **PixelShader** or anything else to the *pipline*, suddenly the GPU crashes and weird somethinges appear on my display screen,
Is there any way to reload the Graphics card instead of restarting the machine :) ?

Comment: You will have to be way more specific. If you have an error you will need to show the exact text of the error as text no pictures of text please. You also most likely need to add  a [mcve] that is fully compliable and produces the error you show but also a minimal program we don't want 100s of lines of code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.